# textSize property of SCNText is missing

Tags: swift, arkit, arscnview, scntext

I want to add a SCNPlane around the SCNText in ARSCNView. therefore I need the textSize of a text which I have created with SCNText like:

[image]

as you can see from the image, there is an error which indicate that the

> SCNText has no member 'textSize'

but I can see the related documentation in apple website for both [SCNText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext) and [textSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext/1523680-textsize).

does anybody know what is the problem and how can I access the textSize property?

I'm using xCode 10.0 beta 4, swift 4.2, macOS Mojave 10.14 Beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `textSize` property is only available on `macOS 10.8+` which is why you can't see it (assuming of course you are building for IOS). By this, I mean that if you are building a MacOS app then the variable is accessible. Whereas if you are building for IOS it is not.

If you want to get the size of your `SCNText` you can use it's `boundingBox` property to get its width and height for example e.g:

```
 //1. Get The Bounding Box Of The Text Node
 let boundingBox = textNode.boundingBox

 //2. Get The Width & Height Of Our Node
 let width = boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x
 let height = boundingBox.max.y - boundingBox.min.y
```

If you just want to set the fontSize you can do something like so:

```
 //1. Create An SCNNode With An SCNText Geometry
 let textNode = SCNNode()
 let textGeometry = SCNText(string: "StackOverflow", extrusionDepth: 1)
 textGeometry.font = UIFont(name: "Skia-Regular_Black", size: 20)
```

Remembering of course that when you specify the font size in `ARKit`, this in meters.

Hope it helps...

Comment: I’m using macOS 10.14

Comment: These calculations with boundingBox is giving the exact size of the text?

Comment: The property is available when making an Xcode Project for MacOS. If you are making an IOS app then you cannot use the texSize property.

Comment: Yes... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnboundingvolume

Comment: Thanks @Josh I solved the problem with your help and also answered a complete guide to how to cover a textNode with a PlaneNode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51961959/1724845).